# iTextSharp - How to add a PDFPRow to a PDFPTable?

Tags: c#, itext

I would like to add an array of PDFPCells to a PDFPRow, then add the PDFPRow to a PDFPTable, but I can't seem to find a method within PDFPTable for this.

There is however a PDFPTable.AddCell

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out the `PdfPTable`'s `Rows.Add()` method which takes a PdfPRow, which you can construct using an array of `PdfPCells`.

Example:

```
// ...
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
PdfPCell[] cells = new PdfPCell[] { new PdfPCell(GetCell("c1")),
                                    new PdfPCell(GetCell("c2")),
                                    new PdfPCell(GetCell("c3")),
                                    new PdfPCell(GetCell("c4")),
                                    new PdfPCell(GetCell("c5"))};
PdfPRow row = new PdfPRow(cells);
table.Rows.Add(row);
// ...
```

Where the method `GetCell()` returns a `PdfPCell`.

Comment: I also prefer the approach Kukoy is seeking. I tried @Jay Rigg's code, but often ends in an error which says Can't access the file that has been closed.  The problem is iTextSharp does not encourage this approach according to Bruno http://stackoverflow.com/a/19874992/97109. I wonder why.