# iTextSharp - Use Colspan with PdfPRow

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, rows, pdfptable

I am able to create multiple rows if they contain the same number of columns:

```
table = new PdfPTable(3);

var firstRowCell1 = new PdfPCell( new Phrase ("Row 1 - Column 1"));
var firstRowCell2 = new PdfPCell( new Phrase ("Row 2 - Column 2"));
var firstRowCell3 = new PdfPCell( new Phrase ("Row 3 - Column 3"));
PdfPCell[] row1Cells = { firstRowCell1, firstLineRow2, firstRowCell3 };
var row1 = new PdfPRow(row1Cells);
table.Rows.Add(row1);

var nextRowCell1 = new PdfPCell( new Phrase ("Row 2 - Column 1"));
var nextRowCell2 = new PdfPCell( new Phrase ("Row 2 - Column 2"));
var nextRowCell3 = new PdfPCell( new Phrase ("Row 2 - Column 3"));
PdfPCell[] row2Cells = { nextRowCell1, nextRowCell2, nextRowCell3 };
var row2 = new PdfPRow(row2Cells);
table.Rows.Add(row2);
```

This works fine giving me two rows each with three columns.

[image]

However if I want the first row to just have one long column using Colspan it disappears:

```
var table = new PdfPTable(3);  

var firstRowCell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Row 1 - Column 1"));
firstRowCell1.Colspan = 3;
PdfPCell[] row1Cells = { firstRowCell1 };
var row1 = new PdfPRow(row1Cells);
deptHeaderTable.Rows.Add(row1);

var nextRowCell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Row 2 - Column 1"));
var nextRowCell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Row 2 - Column 2"));
var nextRowCell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Row 2 - Column 3"));
PdfPCell[] row2Cells = { nextRowCell1, nextRowCell2, nextRowCell3 };
var row2 = new PdfPRow(row2Cells);
deptHeaderTable.Rows.Add(row2);
```

[image]

There are no errors given it just simply does not render.

Additionally, I am aware of table.AddCell which automatically starts a new row when the table column limit is reached for the current row.  However, I want to use PdfPRow if at all possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Seems like you've read documentation that isn't endorsed by the original iText developer (being me). May I ask you for the URL where you've found that documentation, so that I can ask for a cease and desist?

As for the answer to your question: please take a look at [the official documentation](http://itextpdf.com/learn), and you'll find the [MyFirstTable](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=75) example. Based on this example, you can adapt your own code as follows:

```
var table = new PdfPTable(3);
var cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell with colspan 3"));
cell.Colspan = 3;
table.AddCell(cell);
table.AddCell("row 2; cell 1");
table.AddCell("row 2; cell 2");
table.AddCell("row 2; cell 3");
```

As you can see, there's no reason to use the `PdfPRow` class. The `PdfPRow` class is used internally by iText, but as documented in my book, developers using iText shouldn't use that class in their code.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  I will switch my code over to using AddCell() and have it automatically start the next row when the colspan is reached. I'll put a comment between each "row" for readability.

I was exploring the public methods of the iTextSharp.text.pdf; namespace and found PdfPRow along side PdfPTable and PdfPCell.

Additionally, there are several examples of using it on this site:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043848/itextsharp-how-to-add-a-pdfprow-to-a-pdfptable

and a few on some external sites:
http://jexp.ru/index.php/Java_Tutorial/PDF/Table_Row

Thanks again!

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie: No wonder that most examples have table.AddCell instead of table.Rows.Add(somePdfPRow object). I still think that it is more natural to create cells, add these cells to a row and then add the row to table.Rows. Using table.AddCell only makes it very hard to track down where I added an extra cell or where I missed one cell, because it'll blindly add cells to the table and start a new row when the number of defined columns has exhausted in a single row. Do you agree?

Comment: Personally, I think it's easier to let iText handle all the row stuff, but that's a matter of opinion. There are pros and cons for both approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Though I would recommend using code as per the official documentation as recommended above by the original Author (Thank you sir !!!), there is a way to resolve the issue:

```
    public static void TestFunction()
    {
        string[] cells = new string[] { "C1", "C2", "C3", "C6" };
        float[] columnWidths = new float[] { 25f, 25f, 25f, 25f, 25f, 25f };
        int[] colSpans = new int[] { 1, 1, 3, 1 };

        PdfPTable pdfPTable = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);

        var row = CreatePdfRow(cells, colSpans);
        pdfPTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    public static PdfPRow CreatePdfRow(string[] cells, int[] colSpans = null)
    {
        // parameter values passed for cells and colSpans:
        // string[] cells = new string[]{ "C1", "C2", "C3", "C6"};
        // int[] colSpans = new int[] { 1,1,3,1};

        if (cells == null || cells.Length <= 0)
            return new PdfPRow(new PdfPCell[] { new PdfPCell(new Phrase("")) });

        List<PdfPCell> Cells = new List<PdfPCell>();

        for (var i = 0; i < cells.Length; i++)
        {
            var pdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cells[i] ?? ""));

            if (colSpans != null && colSpans.Length > i)
                pdfPCell.Colspan = colSpans[i];

            Cells.Add(pdfPCell);

            // For cells with ColSpan > 1, add null cells to fill up the empty spots
            if (colSpans != null && colSpans.Length > i && colSpans[i] > 1)
            {
                for (var j = 1; j < colSpans[i]; j++)
                {
                    Cells.Add(null);
                }
            }
        }

        PdfPRow row = new PdfPRow(Cells.ToArray());
        return row;
    }
```